# Can "brandy" be used as adjective of "brand"?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

In the same context as of "Trendy names", why is "*Brandy* names" not used?

*Brandy* comes naturally/intuitively as an adjective to *brand* in the minds of a new English speaker, instead of the commonly used words like *brandworthy*, *brandable*, *branded*.

I want to understand the reason behind such usage. If we assume the word brandy does not denote a specific alcoholic beverage, is it grammatically correct to use "brandy" as an adjective of *brand*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. How would you use this "adjective"?

Comment: Neither [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brandy) nor [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brandy) list **brandy** as an adjective (nor under **brand**). Why don't English speakers use it as an adjective relating to **brand**? Because they don't: language development and usage don't follow logic. If you use it in the way you propose, you may be misunderstood.

Comment: An item is described as **branded** if it belongs to a brand. This is an example of a participle being used as an adjective. (To avoid ambiguity with the noun 'brandy' meaning the spirit.) The adverb would then be 'brandedly' : if one wanted to express something behaving (or being used) in a branded way.

Comment: @jsw29 The usage I am looking at is, how to differentiate a "brand-worthy" (in my mind I am still saying brandy) label/inscription/logo/icon/name/id and a "so-so" label. Maybe using a qualifier like "good brand" (vs a meh brand) instead of "brandy" will be more acceptable. What are your thoughts?

Comment: As far as I can understand from this thread, its more because of the popularly accepted usage over time, that brandy has been kindof assigned its current meaning. But still english has a lot of dual meaning/usage words, don't understand why brandy is never used for this "brandiness" (as a method of evaluating the brandability of a label) definition.

Comment: @grv perhaps it will. If enough people say, for example "That name isn't brandy enough" the usage will find its way into dictionaries. Just because *you* think it's a 'natural' way to say it, doesn't mean that it should be.

Comment: @WeatherVane, that makes sense. it all boils down to the popular usage. "popular English" language should already be promoted as an AI organism, dynamically capturing/absorbing the essence of the times its in, just like how real organisms do. Kudos.

Comment: @grv your "brandy has been kind of assigned its current meaning" is false. There is no English language committee setting rules and assigning meanings. The language 'rules' are just guidelines to help formulate sentences.

Comment: I've heard *brandy new* as a standard joke. Not just brand new, but brandy new.

Comment: Put a hyphen before the y to differentiate.

Comment: It’s no problem to use *brand-y* as an adjective (note the hyphen to disambiguate it from the drink). But it means *brand-like* or *brand-ish* — not *brandworthy*, as you seem to suggest.

Comment: It is a perfectly good question to ask even if it is impossibly Wrong! in its premise. Go Lambie!

Comment: The word 'brand' itself **can be its own adjective form**, too:  for example, the "Brand vs. Basic" series on YouTube (by *Nate from the Internet*).  There's also the adjective usage of "name-brand" to contrast with "off brand" or "store brand" - like *Kleenex* or *Puffs* would be 'name brand' tissues, vs. a store brand like *Great Value*.  Maybe the fact that the word 'brand' itself can be an adjective precludes the formation of a separate adjective ending in *-y*?  Like the 'flat adverbs' which have the same form as their corresponding adjectives instead of adding *-ly*

Answer (score 5):

The absence of *brandy* as an adjective, formed from the noun 'brand', simply shows that there is no evidence for its being part of standard English.

It is not included as an adjective in the Cambridge English dictionary or Collins English dictionary, among British dictionaries; nor does it feature in Merriam Webster (American English).

There are nouns that do show up as adjectives by the addition of the letter *y* to the noun, such as '*flighty*', formed from the noun 'flight', or '*handy'*, derived from '*hand*'

Why not '*brandy*'?  Well, the word has already been bagged by a famous alcoholic drink.  Also, the word '*brand*' itself came to be used in the sense of OP relatively recently.  Etymonline dates it from 1889 [https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=brand].

This connection would be a good reason for not bothering to coin 'brandy' and see whether it catches on:  more probably, it would sound too silly.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally permissible to add prefixes/suffixes that are in dictionaries, as *-y* is, to words that are in dictionaries, even if the resulting constructions are not themselves in any dictionary. The absence of this sense of *brandy* from dictionaries is thus not sufficient on its own for concluding that it must never, ever be used in the way that the OP proposes. The absence of such a construction from dictionaries is, however, an indication that it is uncommon; its absence form even the most exhaustive dictionaries is an indication that it is **very** uncommon. A writer who is considering using it, therefore, has to exercise judgement as to whether the aptness of the construction for the writer's purpose outweighs the risk of its being confusing or perceived as awkward. In this case the risk is very high, as the word already has a well established unrelated meaning, which is likely to distract the readers, even if they eventually 'get' what was intended.

Comment: A word doesn't even have to be listed on a dictionary to qualify as a word. It simply must be understandable when presented to the intended audience of the user. It's too easy to forget that dictionaries are not authoritative lists. No dictionary worth its salt claims to be a complete list of every word, nor can any hope to be.

Comment: The context is probably more important than that it has another meaning. If you said “I hate it when companies plaster their products with bright colours, huge logos and their names in large fonts. It’s just too brandy for me.” No one would think you are talking about the alcohol. But, if I was doing it in writing I’d use “brand-y”.

Comment: @R Mac 'Word' remains ill-defined. 'understandable when presented to the intended audience of the user' means that a given candidate may be a word on Tuesday but not on Wednesday. And what if 2% say of an audience know what the candidate means? And 4% think they do but are mistaken? There needs to be _some_ minimum level of currency and comprehension, but until Webster's, OED or Wiktionary grant it acceptance, how does one really define wordness?

Answer (score 1):

The word "brand" comes to English from Old English "brand", which means "burning". It progressed from this original meaning into Middle English, when it meant "to mark by application of a hot iron". You can see the connection between these two meanings.

The modern English word "brand" comes in turn from the Middle English word. The modern definition, meaning "an identifying name given to a product line", appreciably embodies the Middle English word's meaning--being a process by which farmers would mark farm animals and slave owners would mark slaves as "theirs".

You can perhaps see why there is no directly connected adjective form of this word in use. There cannot be degrees of branding to a thing. A thing is either branded or not.

Remember that context is an important condition to correct interpretation of language. Because you can't have degrees of branding, the word "brandy" to most people will not immediately evoke the intended root.

But I think probably that the simplest explanation for why such a word doesn't exist in English is that not enough people in all the history of the English language have had a need for such a word. With no need to drive its use, said word simply never came to be.

Comment: As can be discerned from some of the comments below the question, the sense in which the OP would like to use the word is not **branded** (which is indeed not a matter of degree), but rather **suitable for use as a brandname** (which is a matter of degree).

Comment: The word "brand" meaning a modern product line name is etymologically related to the Old English word "brand". I clearly indicated this in the post. I am aware they are not the same word.

Comment: Further, the "-y" suffix applied to a noun does not indicate suitability for a purpose. Rather it indicates magnitude (positive and presumably high) and is often figurative. See peachy, testy, and risky. This is, as I see it, a big reason why "brandy" is not used. Because a word or phrase is either a brand name or it is not. It's not commonly understood that a phrase or word can be characterized by the qualities of a brand name. What even are the qualities of a brand name?

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers do "coin" ad hoc adjectives by analogy in that manner but they will do something, either verbally, with an intonation, or with a gesture like so-called "scare quotes", to indicate that they're doing so. In writing you might find a hyphen used to indicate the coinage, the ad hoc nature of the adjective: "brand-y":

> The new university logo is a tad too *brand-y* for my tastes. Did the Communications team hire the same people who did the logo for Meta?
>
> The design for our new breakfast cereal box is too *off-brand-ish*. Consumers will think "health food" but we want them to feel excited about each and every spoonful.

Comment: If these are actual quotations, it should be indicated what their sources are.

Comment: They are not. I pulled them out of my *rse.